# Python Output from Multiple Inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a Python program, there are multiple inputs that are converted into integers, then the programs will use one of this input recursively and deliver correpsonding outputs.

To illustrate better, here is the illustration:

```
    # the below 2 lines are given / mandatory:
    for a0 in range(q):
        angle = int(input().strip())

    # my codes: 
    function 1...
    function 2...
    function 3...
    ...
    print(result)
```

The functions are correct and print the desired output. However, since there are multiple inputs (angle), my result only used the last input value (angle).

The input format is

```
    90
    180
    270
```

The desired output format should be

```
    10
    6
    22
```

My code only allows me to get 22.

Could you help explain how I could fix this problem and generate the desired outputs?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You should read the page on creating a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why don't you just call your functions inside the `for` loop?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to use some sort of list in order to keep all the inputs. It seems that you rewrite the `angle` variable and this is why it keeps only the last input.

For instance:

```
angles = []

# the below 2 lines are given / mandatory:

for a0 in range(q):
    angles.append(int(input().strip()))


# here you functions use the `angles` list like angles[0], angles[1] etc.
# my codes: 
function 1...
function 2...
function 3...
```

Comment: Thank you. This is how I resolved the problem. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @GSu I am glad it helped you and if it did you can accept the answer and upvote it. Someone downvoted my answer for some unknown reason.